# Method changing, then returning received parameter; is it good or bad?

Tags: java, pseudocode

I'm working on a project where we have a method like this:

```java
processEvent(event, context) {
    // var result = some processing here
    context.setResult(result);
    // context's class have nothing to do with processEvent's class
    return context;
}
```

The class `SomeClass` containing `processEvent` method has no inheritance relation with `context`'s class (so it's not about a builder pattern here). For me, the `context` returning is silly because the *direct* caller would already have it. Are any other more plausible arguments in favor of or against this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uncommon to have a method return one of its parameters' values if it doesn't have any other return value. It enables code like this:

```
Context context = processEvent(event, new Context(/*...*/));
```

Whether that's good or bad style is, er, a matter of style. :-) It's not all that common, but I wouldn't say it's uncommon, either.

Comment: I think the thing which is bad about this is that it's unclear that it would do anything to change the context: "process event" suggests it does things to the event. A more explicit name would help.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Agreed for this example. We have a few of these in the JavaScript std lib that don't feel problematic, because of the name/purpose of the function. `Object.assign(target, source1, source2, source3/*...*/)` returns `target`, for instance. :-) (Less clear is `Object.defineProperty(object, name, options)` which returns the object...)

Comment: @AndyTurner - nice valid answer! thank you